# Completing the square

Tags: completing-the-square

Can someone explain what happens from step 6 forward, when solving 3x^2 – 12x – 7 = 0 by completing the square. How does radical of 19/3 turn into radical 57/ 3?[image]

Comment: $19\cdot 3=57$.  The person who wrote this decided to [rationalize the denominator](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radicals5.htm).

Comment: A friendly reminder that you may always *"add zero"* or *"multiply by one"* and it will not change anything.  The trick is what "zero" or what "one" you use.  Take the very first step for example.  Step zero might have rather looked like $3x^2-12x + (12-12) - 7 = 0$.  Step 6.5 might have looked like $x-2 = \pm \frac{\sqrt{19}}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}})$, noting that $(12-12)=0$ and that $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with completing the square.  Your confusion is in ["rationalizing the demoninator"](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radicals5.htm) (usually a square root--but that need not be the case).

In your case you have $\frac{\sqrt{19}}{\sqrt{3}}$.  We would "like" to get rid of the divide by an irrational number (although this is an unnecessary step introduced largely for arbitrary reasons by high school math teachers--but it *does* teach you some properties of fractional powers).  To get rid of it, we simply multiply by a special form of "1":

$$
\frac{\sqrt{19}}{\sqrt{3}}*\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3*19}}{\sqrt{3*3}} = \frac{\sqrt{57}}{3}
$$

That simplification has nothing to do with completing the square--it's just a simplification which would have been just as correct to leave it out and keep the answer as:

$$
2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{19}{3}}
$$

**Another Example of Rationalizing the denominator:**

I don't like it when you see nothing but square roots.  Here's another example:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}
$$

We *don't* multiply by $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ because this doesn't rationalize the denominator...we need to get a whole value for $2$:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} * \frac{\sqrt[3]{2^2}}{\sqrt[3]{2^2}} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{\sqrt[3]{2^3}} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{2}
$$

Had it been $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$ then we could have either done $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}*\frac{\sqrt[3]{16}}{\sqrt[3]{16}} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2^4}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2^3*2}}{4} = \frac{2*\sqrt[3]{2}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}$ *or* we could already recognize that $\sqrt[3]{4} = \sqrt[3]{2^2}$ which is only lacking a $\sqrt[3]{2}$:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}*\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{3}$ and you get

$$\sqrt{\frac{19}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{57}}{3}$$

Comment: Could you explain why we do that?

Comment: Is it because in the standard form you cannot have a radical in the denominator?

Comment: Not to have radicals in the denominator so numbers look like $p+q\sqrt{•}$ where $p$ and $q$ are rationals $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{•}]$ is a field

Comment: OP is asking about completing the square and you're talking about field theory?  LOL.

Comment: This is the reason besides "why not" that historically rationalizing denominators was explored. It was to show that the inverse of $p+q\sqrt{•}$ is of the same form

Comment: I have to completely agree with Bye_World. It is more of an aesthetic thing. Just like how some people prefer to write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ over $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: @Bye_World Actually the OP is confused about step 6, which is a simplification (which rationalizes the denominator) and has nothing to do really with completing the square.

Comment: @Jared OK. But either way...